# Why I have error overlapping range is not allowed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building formatter extension. Unfortunately I cannot find a lot of examples how to tackle simple tasks.

This is my files Formatter provider and I try to capitalize some keywords. This works first time after extension refresh but not second time.

What did I do wrong?

```ts
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class STFormatterProvider implements vscode.DocumentFormattingEditProvider {

    public out: Array<vscode.TextEdit> = [];

    provideDocumentFormattingEdits(document: vscode.TextDocument) {
        this.capitalize(document);

        return this.out;
    }

    capitalize(document: vscode.TextDocument) {
        let keywords = ['true', 'false', 'exit', 'continue', 'return', 'constant', 'retain'];

        for (let line = 0; line < document.lineCount; line++) {
            const element = document.lineAt(line);
            let regEx = new RegExp(`\\b(${keywords.join('|')})\\b`, "ig");
            let result = element.text.match(regEx);
            if (result && result.length > 0) {
                let str = element.text.replace(regEx, (match, content) => {
                    return match.toUpperCase();
                });

                this.out.push(
                    vscode.TextEdit.replace(element.range, str)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `TextEditor::edit()`. First collect all possible replaces on the document and then call `TextEditor::edit()` and apply all edits to the `editBuilder`.This way there is possibility of ranges overlapping. Why create a new regex for each line. Just reset `lastIndex` if needed when using the `replace` call.

Comment: I am following this example https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices and I do not have `editBuilder` or `textEditor` there. Second how to reset `lastIndex` using the `replace`?

Comment: how do you handle keywords inside string literals and comments?

Comment: I did not. How should I? I also very blury to see how to indent. What would you suggest?

Comment: you need to add a parser for your language and use the parse tree to guide the formatting

Comment: Should I use LSP? I am scared by this. I tryed to use it few times but could not grasp a concept and always failed.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you have this `overlap range` is that you don't reset the `out` array.

I have also performed a few other refactors

```
class STFormatterProvider implements vscode.DocumentFormattingEditProvider {

  public out: Array<vscode.TextEdit> = [];

  provideDocumentFormattingEdits(document: vscode.TextDocument) {
      this.out = [];
      this.capitalize(document);
      return this.out;
  }

  capitalize(document: vscode.TextDocument) {
      let keywords = ['true', 'false', 'exit', 'continue', 'return', 'constant', 'retain'];

      let regEx = new RegExp(`\\b(${keywords.join('|')})\\b`, "ig");
      for (let lineNr = 0; lineNr < document.lineCount; ++lineNr) {
          const line = document.lineAt(lineNr);
          if (regEx.test(line.text)) {
              let str = line.text.replace(regEx, (match) => { return match.toUpperCase(); });
              this.out.push( vscode.TextEdit.replace(line.range, str) );
          }
      }
  }
}
```