# Problem format code (for clean code) in visual studio code (VSC)

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

[image]I Have Problem to use `format document` by shortcut key `Alt+Shift+F` in my `javascript` code on `VSC`.
that some times have popup error in below right of window :

> Overlapping ranges are not allowed!

any body explain why that warning show and how to fix that?

part of code:

```
    render() {
        console.log("sart_azmoon");


        return (
            <View style={{
                backgroundColor: color.khakestarikam, width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
            }} >


   

                    <View style={{

                        marginLeft: "4%", marginRight: "4%",
                        marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 30,
                        borderBottomRightRadius: responsiveWidth(3),
                        borderBottomLeftRadius: responsiveWidth(3),

                    }}>

                        <View style={{
                            backgroundColor: '#757575', borderTopRightRadius: responsiveWidth(3),
                            borderTopLeftRadius: responsiveWidth(3)
                        }}>
                            <Text style={{
                                color: "white", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2.5),
                                textAlign: "center", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), justifyContent: 'center'
                            }}>
                                </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{
                            backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomRightRadius: responsiveWidth(3),
                            borderBottomLeftRadius: responsiveWidth(3),
                        }}>
                            <FlatList
                                // showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                contentContainerStyle={{
                                    flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center',
                                    alignItems: 'center'
                                }}
                                style={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                    marginTop: 4,

                                    // backgroundColor: 'yellow',

                                }}
                                // horizontal={true}
                                // keyExtractor={(data) => data.ExamId}
                                data={this.state.GroupList}
                                renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                                    (

                                        <GroupList
                                            item={item}
                                        />

                                    )
                                }


                            />
                            <View style={{ height: responsiveHeight(5), }} />
                        </View>

                    </View>


                    <View style={{

                        flexDirection: "row", marginLeft: "4%", marginRight: "4%",
                        marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 0
                    }}>
                        <Text style={{
                            color: "#ff4646", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2.5),
                            textAlign: "left", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            ⬤
                        </Text>

                        <Text style={{
                            color: "#757575", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(1.7),
                            textAlign: "left", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), marginTop: responsiveHeight(0.5),
                        }}>
                        </Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={{

                        flexDirection: "row", marginLeft: "4%", marginRight: "4%",
                        marginBottom: 0
                    }}>
                        <Text style={{
                            color: "#ff4646", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2.5),
                            textAlign: "left", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            ⬤
                        </Text>

                        <Text style={{
                            color: "#757575", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(1.7),
                            textAlign: "left", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), marginTop: responsiveHeight(0.5),
                            marginRight: responsiveHeight(4),
                        }}>
                        </Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={{

                        flexDirection: "row", marginLeft: "4%", marginRight: "4%",
                        marginBottom: 80
                    }}>
                        <Text style={{
                            color: "#ff4646", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2.5),
                            textAlign: "left", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            ⬤
                        </Text>

                        <Text style={{
                            color: "#757575", fontFamily: font.font_black, fontSize: responsiveFontSize(1.7),
                            textAlign: "left", marginLeft: responsiveHeight(2), marginTop: responsiveHeight(0.5),
                            marginRight: responsiveHeight(4),
                        }}>
                        </Text>
                    </View>


                </ScrollView>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default start_azmoon;
```

source link , thank you for attentions.
My sample code for Error occur that link : [Code Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vu4ksn3sncrss1m/detailazmon.js?dl=0)

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: in this question sample code most check completely and some part of code not help users to check and answer this problem ,my source is to long and you know 30,000 limit char for question in stackoverflow then I have to send link of source

Comment: Please see the advice here: [mcve]

Comment: i edit my post can you check that ?@Quentin

Comment: can check again please@T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Code Formatting:
First of all, install the `prettier` extension if haven't already.

Link for [esbenp.prettier-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

- Now go to `File>Preferences>Settings>`
- Search `format`
- Set Default Formatter to `esbenp.prettier-vscode`
- Enable `Format On Save` option

After your settings should look like this:

[image]

About Overallaping Error check: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618542/why-i-have-error-overlapping-range-is-not-allowed)

Comment: I install this extension and follow this, but when I save code that's not format and no happening , When i Press Shift+Alt+f  i Get Before error too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing in React. In my case I narrowed it down to occurring when there was a blank line with two or more spaces between tags. Example: the .tsx file below wouldn't format unless I delete one of the two spaces on line 6. I filed a bug report on vscode. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114499

```
import React from 'react';
function App(): JSX.Element {
return (
    <div className="App">
<a  href="https://reactjs.org" >Learn React

</a>

    </div>
);
}
```